# Nokogiri: wrap top-level text elements with <p> tags

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Having trouble building the XPath selector for "naked" text nodes that are not already contained by another tag. I'd like to transform this:

```
some naked text <p>some wrapped text</p> more naked text
```

into this:

```
<p>some naked text</p> <p>some wrapped text</p> <p>more naked text</p>
```

I tried using `doc.xpath("//child::text()").wrap('<p></p>')` but that seems to grab *all* text nodes, not just the top-level ones.

Comment: Yes `//` will select: "_Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are._" Try `"/*/text()` for text in the root element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doc.xpath('/html/body/text()').wrap('<p/>')
```

When you use `//` you are choosing the `descendant-or-self` axis, i.e. anywhere in the document. Instead you want to use `/` and (the default `child` axis) to match only text nodes that are direct children of a particular element.

If this is not an HTML document with `<html>` and `<body>` elements, then simply:

```
doc.xpath('/*/text()').wrap('<p/>')
```

will select all text elements that are children of the root XML element (whatever its name).

Comment: The /html/body is the part I was missing. My doc is built up from a fragment of HTML text without any <html><body></body></html> container, but Nokogiri was creating those tags for me unexpectedly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could find every text except those inside paragraphs.

```
'//text()[not(ancestor::p)]'
```

Comment: This will wrap `<h1>foo</h1>`, for example, or `<ul><li>bar</li></ul>`